# Opening activity in landscape mode without locking the orientation

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, android-orientation

I want to open an activity initially in Landscape orientation but i don't want to lock that orientation.That means user can switch the orientation on rotating.I tried adding below code to activity.It opens the activity in Landscape mode but its locked.

```
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` on your activity , you can handle what to do when orientation will be change .

```
@override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
         //change orientation here

   } else if (newConfig.orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE{
        //change orientation here
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Add this line in your activity tag in Android Manifest.xml

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Like the following:

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.abc.def.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```